# PyAudio outputs slow/crackling/garbled audio

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, portaudio, pyaudio

I'm trying to use pyaudio to play some wave files but I'm always having slow/crackling/garbled outputs.

When I play this wave file as described bellow, the audio plays just fine:

```
$ wget http://www.freespecialeffects.co.uk/soundfx/sirens/police_s.wav
$ aplay police_s.wav
```

However, when I open the *'play_wave.py'* example from */pyaudio/test*, the audio is so slow and garbled that is useless for any application.

```
"""PyAudio Example: Play a wave file."""

import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

CHUNK = 1024

#if len(sys.argv) < 2:
#    print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s filename.wav" % sys.argv[0])
#    sys.exit(-1)

wf = wave.open('police_s.wav', 'rb')

# instantiate PyAudio (1)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# open stream (2)
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
            output=True)

# read data
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

# play stream (3)
while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

# stop stream (4)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

# close PyAudio (5)
p.terminate()
```

To reproduce a similar poor quality on your laptop/PC, just make the CHUNK = 1 (the output is pretty similar on my Ubuntu)

## **Additional information:**

**What I tried:**

**1-** Another Raspberry Pi B+.

**2-** Change the audio samples per buffer:

As I was supposing the problem was the audio samples per buffer (the CHUNK variable in this example), I made a loop to increment the CHUNK by 1 and played the audio for each increment. I could notice a slight difference for some CHUNK values, but nothing even close to the quality that I get when I play it by aplay. However, I could notice a big difference between this two files:

1- police_s.wav = 8 bits , 22000Hz, Mono , 176 kb/s -> Way better than the beat.wav played by the same CHUNK (2048)

2- beat.wav = 16bits , 44100Hz, Stereo, 1411 kb/s

When I play the same audio through the example */pyaudio/test/play_wave_callback.py*, the output is almost perfect, excepting some interruptions at the end of the audio. So I saw that it doesn't set the CHUNK. It uses the *frame_count* parameter in the callback function, so I printed it and saw that it was 1024 ¬¬, the same default value that came with the example */pyaudio/test/play_wave.py* and that results in a garbled audio.

**3-** pyaudio 0.2.4:
Since [hayderOICO](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=103190&p=715696&hilit=pyaudio&sid=0c83a5c77d4bf10b94f4b641c6c149f8#p715696) mentioned he was using pyaudio 0.2.4 and said "I'm using PyAudio fine.", I decided to give a try on that older version but I got the same result...

**4-** Added   *disable_audio_dither=1*   to config.txt

**I'm using:**      Raspberry Pi B+         Raspbian         python 2.7.3          pyaudio v0.2.8         portaudio19-dev         TRRS analog audio

**How I installed everything:**

*1st try:*

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -y install python-dev python-numpy cython python-smbus portaudio19-dev
$ git clone http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git
$ cd pyaudio
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

*2nd try:*

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
```

*3rd try:*

From GitHub: https://github.com/jleb/pyaudio

It's very frustrating having the library's example not working properly on Pi. I don't think it's a hardware limitation since the same audio plays well with aplay and other libraries like pygame and SDL2.

I am new to Raspberry Pi and audio programming, so I hope to be doing something stupid...
As I am already using a specific wrapper for pyaudio, I really would like to keep using it instead of moving to another library...
I appreciate any help, suggestions and advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've noticed that the playback is smooth if I play the whole stream at once, but garbled if I do it by chunks in a loop. It seems that while loop can't keep up with the playback, so it skips between chunks. I tried setting `frames_per_buffer` higher, so it would buffer several chunks before playback, but that just shortens the playback time.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my raspberry pi (and on my mac). In my experience the pyaudio library is a pain to work with (after 2 weeks of battling it, I ended up using pygame). What worked for me was to check the default sample rate of the audio out and check that its the same and play sounds back as numpy arrays.

So on the RPi, I'd check (extrapolating from ubuntu here...) the files

```
/etc/pulse/daemon.conf
and

/etc/asound.conf or 
~/.asoundrc
```

Does direct playback of numpy arrays work? If so you could do it in a roundabout way...  Here is some code to test if you like

```
import pyaudio 
import numpy as np


def gensin(frequency, duration, sampRate):

    """ Frequency in Hz, duration in seconds and sampleRate
        in Hz"""

    cycles = np.linspace(0,duration*2*np.pi,num=duration*sampRate)
    wave = np.sin(cycles*frequency,dtype='float32')
    t = np.divide(cycles,2*np.pi)

    return t, wave

frequency=8000 #in Hz
duration=1 #in seconds
sampRate=44100 #in Hz

t, sinWav = gensin(frequency,duration,sampRate)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format = pyaudio.paInt32, 
                channels = 1, 
                rate = sampRate, 
                output = True)

stream.start_stream()

stream.write(sinWav)
```

This worked on my RPi and mac, but as said before I ended up using pygame because  even with on and off ramps I couldn't get rid of crackling at the beginning and end and sample rate wasn't something that could be easily changed. I would really recommend against pyaudio, but if you are set on it I wish you the best of luck! :)

Comment: Finally someone that solved it!
I tried to find those files you mentioned on my RPi. I found **.asoundrc** but I couldn't find the **daemon.conf**. 
As far as I understood your answer, I should check if these files are with the same sample rate, but I didn't find any *sample rate* reference in [.asoundrc](http://imgur.com/9Kp7CdG).

I'm sorry, but I'm totally new on RPi and audio programming, I really don't know how to check the default sample rate on these files as you asked me to do...
I know it's a pain in the ass, but could you write in a more detailed way how did you fixed that?

Comment: My program is running perfectly on Ubuntu. I am stuck on this problem around one month and it's the only problem I have to solve to keep my project going... I just need to play a *.wav* through **'play_wave.py'**  with the same quality that it's played by **aplay** and by the example **/pyaudio/test/play_wave_callback.py.**

I tested the code you posted (with no change on "**daemon.conf**" and **"asound.conf"**)  but it still outputs a cracked audio...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @CowOne Did you ever solve this problem with pyaudio? I'm having the same problem. If you did, I'd really appreciate if you share your findings. Thanks!

Comment: hey @LoganYang. I did not manage to solve it :/ I stopped trying after a while and did not have time for that anymore...

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same issue on Raspberry Pi with pyaudio. Using a higher value of chunk size (e.g. 40960) and passing it by frames_per_buffer
upon p.open would make music playback much smoother, less popping and static noise comparing to the smaller value of chunk size (e.g. 1024).

Comment: A follow-up, using PyAudio non-blocking mode with default frame buffer size of 1024  can also resolve the popping/static noise issue on Raspberry Pi board.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. But this fixed it: As the first response says, just pass the "frames_per_buffer" argument to the p.open call:

```
CHUNK=4096
wf = wave.open(filename, 'rb')
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
    channels=wf.getnchannels(),
    rate=wf.getframerate(),
    output=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
while len(data) > 0:
    print(len(data))
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
```